# VSTS What User Account does Hosted Agent run under?

Tags: azure-devops, windows-server-2012, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are trying to setup Release (continuous deployment) from our VSTS in the cloud. After the build is done, the Hosted Agent VS2017 tries to deploy the artifacts to the target server.

Firstly, it failed because our firewall blocked the target server from receiving the artifact (a **.zip** containing all the stuff). In fact, if I connect to the server via RDP and try to download the artifact from a browser, it's blocked.

Our security team temporarily disabled this firewall rule, and it worked (this also means the hosted agent has line of sight for the target server). Now, they don't want this rule off, they would like to know what is the **User Account** that tries to download/publish the artifact from the hosted agent, so they would allow the download of the **.zip** only for that specific user. I'm not sure if it's the same account which runs the service in the Host Agent, or if it's Network Service (therefore the own target server credentials), os some other account.

How do I know what user account should be granted rights in our firewall to download anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Windows Machine File Copy` task, you can provide a username/password to use for copying the files.

However, it uses RoboCopy over SMB to copy the files. As a result, it's probably going to be safer to set up a private agent within your network that has line-of-sight to the target servers, rather than opening up holes in your firewall a whole slew of ports.